# Remove comma character in multi line expression using SED

Tags: regex, bash, sed, multiline

I have a text file like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_user_idx` (`user_id`,`user_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_user_attribute1_idx` (`user_attribute1`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `table_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_product_idx` (`product_id`,`product_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_product_attribute1_idx` (`product_attribute1`),


) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table_ads` (
  `ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_ad_idx` (`ad_id`,`ad_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_ad_attribute1_idx` (`ad_attribute1`),





) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

As you will notice before the closing parenthesis of each "Create table", there is a line that ends with a **comma** and a variable number of new lines.

In Bash with sed command i want to remove the last comma character to create a valid SQL.

I try some expressions like this

```
sed 's/,[[:space:]]*)//'
```

but it didn't works, probably i need to make a multiline search but i don't know how to do this.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters

Comment: ... and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/391809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu-sed` you can do this using `-z` option:

```sh
sed -zE 's/,\n*(\n\) ENGINE)/\1/g' file.db

CREATE TABLE `table_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_user_idx` (`user_id`,`user_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_user_attribute1_idx` (`user_attribute1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `table_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_product_idx` (`product_id`,`product_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_product_attribute1_idx` (`product_attribute1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table_ads` (
  `ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_ad_idx` (`ad_id`,`ad_attribute1`),
  KEY `fk_ad_attribute1_idx` (`ad_attribute1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use GNU's `sed` extensions, you can still do it with standard `sed`, but it's cumbersome. For this, I'd choose something like `perl`:

```
perl -e '$lines=join("",<>); $lines =~ s/,\s*\)/\n)/g; print $lines;' < sqlfile
```

Reading from `<>` (same as `<STDIN>`) returns either a line (in scalar context) or an array of all lines (in `wantarray` context). We want a scalar so that we can substiture over multiple lines, therefore I use `join` which takes an array and returns a scalar.

The regex finds `,` followed by 0 or more whitepace characters (newlines included) followed by a `)`. It then replaces what it found with a single newline followed by a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of problem where I like to reverse the file, then we'll remove the trailing comma from the *first* non-empty line *following* a line beginning with a close parenthesis.

```sh
tac file.sql | awk '
  NF && p {sub(/,[[:blank:]]*$/, ""); p = 0}
  $1 == ")" {p = 1}
  1
' | tac
```

`[:blank:]` is the character class consisting of *horizontal* whitespace (space, tab).

Or, how about a nice compact perl one-liner

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/,(?=\s+[)])//g' file.sql
```

The `-0777` option together with `-p` slurps the entire file into the default $_ variable, and automatically prints it.